# How to create explicit dependencies between auth guards in NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have an Auth guard that relies on user object being attached to request:

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext, UseGuards } from "@nestjs/common"
import { DefaultAuthGuard } from "./default.guard"

@Injectable()
export class OwnerGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    return request.user.id === request.params["userId"]
  }
}
```

where the DefaultAuthGuard is simply JwtAuthGuard:

```
import { JwtAuthGuard } from "./jwt.guard"
export { JwtAuthGuard as DefaultAuthGuard }
```

JwtAuthGuard:

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common"
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport"

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard("jwt") {}
```

and that requires using guards like this:

```
@Get(":userId/applications")
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@UseGuards(OwnerGuard)
async list(@Param("userId") userId: string): Promise<ApplicationDto[]> {
  return await this.userApplicationsService.list(userId)
}
```

because JwtAuthGuard is where the log in happens and user object is attached to the request by passport.

I would like to remove this implicit dependency and have something like this:

```
@Get(":userId/applications")
@UseGuards(OwnerGuard)
async list(@Param("userId") userId: string): Promise<ApplicationDto[]> {
  return await this.userApplicationsService.list(userId)
}
```

and my initial approach was to inject JwtAuthGuard into the OwnerGuard as shown below:

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext, UseGuards } from "@nestjs/common"
import { DefaultAuthGuard } from "./default.guard"

@Injectable()
export class OwnerGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly defaultAuthGuard: DefaultAuthGuard) {}
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    await this.defaultAuthGuard.logIn(request)
    return request.user.id === request.params["userId"]
  }
}
```

but that unfortunately yields

```
Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (...passport/lib/http/request.js:46:34)
```

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: Could you add the code for `DefaultAuthGuard` as well please?